# How to install multiple In-house apps ? ( iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing a website to deploy my iPhone applications. Users can select multiple iOS applications from the app list from the website and when they click download, all the applications have to install to the phone one by one. Check All the applications at once - Click Download - Then all the applications will be downloaded and installed automatically. How is it possible? Is there a way I can change this plist file where url dict is an array ?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://web.me.com/macdev/apps/app1.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.macdev.inhouse.app1</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>App Demo</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html), the `items` key is an "array of downloads" so for each app, add a `<dict>` with the app's `assets` and `metadata` in that array:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <!-- array of downloads. -->
   <key>items</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <!-- App #1 -->
           <key>assets</key>
           <array>
               ...
           </array>
           <key>metadata</key>
           <dict>
               ...
           </dict>
       </dict>
       <dict>
           <!-- App #2 -->
           <key>assets</key>
           <array>
               ...
           </array>
           <key>metadata</key>
           <dict>
               ...
           </dict>
       </dict>
   </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When the user taps on the link for this plist, they are asked something like "xyz.com wants to install 2 apps.  Cancel | Install".

Tapping Install starts the download and installation of all the apps.

Comment: it works. Is it anyway that can return back to link that the user clicked before?